# How can I configure spring security for multiple servlets?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to use spring security in a spring mvc application that consists of two modules -- a "frontend" and a management module. Both modules have their own dispatcher servlet (with different mappings) so they do have their own web context, but share the same root context.

The management module has its own authentication database and users should be able to log into the "frontend" and management module simultaneously with different credentials. Therefore I implemented two different `UserDetailsService`s.

I need two different `AuthenticationManager`s where both are responsible for different urls, corresponding to the servlets mappings.

How can I configure such a setup? Is it possible using java config?

Edit: until now I have the following configuration, which allows me to authorize users for the management module. The "frontend" modules authentication / authorization using the autowired `frontendUserDetailsService` is still missing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("frontend")
    private UserDetailsService frontendUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("management")
    private UserDetailsService managementUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(managementUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("management")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/manage/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)?

Comment: Yes I did, but it guides me to configure multiple `HttpSecurity` instances. But this doesn't allow me to configure different `AuthenticationManager`s. I'm just crawling through the source of spring security and believe that it might be possible to override the default behaviour to build an `AuthenticationManager`, but I didn't find a clean solution so far (should work overriding `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManager` and use the multiple `HttpSecurity` approach above).

Comment: Yes it does as you can also override a configure method which allows for setting the authentication manager.

Comment: The `configure` method that gets the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` doesn't help here, because that only allows to configure one single `AuthenticationManager`. But what I need is a second one that has another `UserDetailsService` configured. -- I'll update my question and post the configuration code I have so far.

Comment: You need to specify 2 classes extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which both configure their respective part. You need to override both configure methods not simply add a method that takes an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as that configures a global `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: You shouldn't expose the `AuthenticationManager` as both configuration beans can take care of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create configuration that does a couple of things

1. Enable the security
2. Enable security for the frontend
3. Enable security for the backend

Basically those are 3 different parts of configuration which all require their respective `@Configuration` class.

Something like the following should work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class FrontEndSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("frontend")
        private UserDetailsService frontendUserDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .userDetailsService(frontendUserDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/frontend/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class BackendSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("management")
        private UserDetailsService managementUserDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .userDetailsService(managementUserDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/manage/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

You probably need to tune the

Comment: Thanks for your heads up. I was really close to this solution, but didn't realize, that `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` gets a _local_ instance and not the global `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. As soon as I have tested this setup, I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianRudolph please, explain me how you realized this. I have the same problem, but I can't solve it.

Comment: I did it exactly as suggested in this answer - using nested configuration classes that both provide a spring security configuration.

Comment: @ChristianRudolph: I followed the above solution but there is a small difference that in my case i am injecting authenticationManager into another service and then use authenticationManager  for authentication. In the service it is always going to the same userDetailsService. It's not going to different userDetailsService based on URL. Is it possible to expose multiple authenticationManager beans with different userDetailsServices?