# Spring Boot share beans between servlets

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem with my Spring Boot project. My project have multiple modules. Where many is web modules.

To make the application flexible, isolate spring security settings, base path and others. I would like to create a servlet for each web module.
But I would like to share some beans, so they don't start in all servlets.
For example I would like to reuse the @Component, @Repository, @Service instance from the core module. To save resources and still maintain design flexibility.

Today beans are declared in duplicate, when I call a servlet, follow the example:

```
[main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    :            CORE MODULE INITIALIZED
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   :            STRATEGY MODULE INITIALIZED
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
 br.com.llw.platform.PlatformApplication  : Started PlatformApplication in 3.816 seconds (JVM running for 4.191)
 o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'authRestDispatcherServlet'
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'authRestDispatcherServlet'
 d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
 d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
 s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
 .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: registerUsingPOST_1
                          AuthRestConfig  : ==============================================================
                          AuthRestConfig  :            AUTH REST MODULE INITIALIZED
                          AuthRestConfig  : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                            CoreModule    :            CORE MODULE INITIALIZED
                            CoreModule    : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
                         StrategyModule   :            STRATEGY MODULE INITIALIZED
                         StrategyModule   : ==============================================================
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 448 ms
```

You can see that the bean is recreated when I call a servlet endpoint.

**Any idea how I can get around this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Use a full application server and do an EAR deployment

Comment: generally: you can have 1 "application context"("dispatch servlet"...with beans,security...) + n "servlet contexts" (with custom security/beans/details)

Comment: see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet and here (for security) https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/servlet-api.html (cool, new docs(design)!;)

Comment: I will check, thank you very much!

Comment: Very welcome! sorry for "theoretics", though the links are good... here is a nice (applied&simple) sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572974/592355

Comment: Thanks, I ended up choosing to make a context only. According to your example. Thank you so much!

I had found a nice way to do it using SpringApplicationBuilder but the end result was the same. Context starting beans again.